# Passing google identity from chrome extension to my node.js app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

**Overview:** *I am trying to understand the interactions between OAuth security in my server and in my chrome extension.  I think I have 90% of the answer working, but I'm missing a bit. I'd like to find the cleanest way to finish my implementation using existing tools, rather than reinventing any wheels.*

**Background**: I have a node.js app that uses passport, passport-google-auth, and express-session to authenticate users. I save per-user information, keyed by the user's Google identity.  This works fine. My web pages can exchange data with the app, and the Google login screen pops up correctly in exactly the cases I'd expect.

I also have a chrome extension, which includes a browser_action popup that needs to write data to my node.js app and a content_script that needs to read data from my app.

My extension already uses chrome.identity.getAuthToken to get the user identity.
For testing, if I ignore security, I can pass this id to my node.js app, and access the info I need.

But, this is no good, of course. I want my node.js API to be locked down, only letting in clients that have the cookie generated for me by passport.

*Side note: I imagine, instead, that I could do some song-and-dance wheel reinvention and pass the id securely to my server via https. But this seems completely wrong, right?*

**Question**: I assume that my chrome extension really should be doing the OAuth2 dance directly with my node.js app. But, I don't know what piece I should be using, or how to cleanly play with chrome.identity.  I suspect that I'm just missing a small bit of wisdom, but I don't know what it is.

*Side comment: Because cookies are shared between browser tabs, I can (clumsily) achieve what I want by simply connecting to my node.js app from another tab in the browser. So, I guess I just need to get the same behavior from my extension background page.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest answer for me was to use the Stormpath APIs for this. It took some effort, but was reasonably straightforward.